# WPF Create a slide out panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know how this works technically but my requirement is as follows. I have a `DataGrid` and to input data into the `DataGrid`, I want a panel at the bottom of the `DataGrid` that slides out on a button click showing input options. Except, as the panel slides out, the `DataGrid` has to resize vertically as well. Can someone throw some light on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use a **StackPanel** with 2 children, your grid and your panel. Set the **initial height of your panel to 0**. Once the button is clicked, set the height to whatever you need it to be (e.g., MyPanel.Height = 20). You might want to wrap the grid in a ScrollViewer in case that is needed.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Height="*" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ContentControl x:Name="MyPanel" Height="0" />
</StackPanel>
```

You might need to experiment with VerticalAlignment and Height="Auto" or Height="0" to get the layout you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Expander`. Please look at the following code snippet.

```
 <DockPanel>
        <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Height="25"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="25"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Height="25"></TextBlock>

            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGreen" BorderThickness="2">
            <DataGrid/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel >
```